# What AWS services use AWS lambda behind the scenes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-config, aws-ssm

We were in the process of setting up AWS Config Rules and came across a bug in one of the AWS managed rules. During our conversation with the AWS support person, he has revealed that the AWS Config Rules are processed by AWS Lambda functions behind the scenes.

I am curious to know what other AWS services use AWS Lambda behind the scenes. For example, AWS Systems Manager documents.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Not exhaustive list, but here are some more examples:

- [AWS::Include Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) which is a macro **hosted by AWS CloudFormation**, to insert boilerplate content into your templates.
- [AWS::Serverless Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html) which is a macro **hosted by AWS CloudFormation**, takes an entire template written in the AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM) syntax and transforms and expands it into a compliant AWS CloudFormation template
- [Secret Manager and its password rotation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html): If you use your secret for one of the supported Amazon RDS databases, then **Secrets Manager provides the Lambda function for you**. And Secrets Manager automatically customizes the function to meet the requirements of the specified database.

Comment: Marcin, do you know how are aws systems manager documents processed behind the scenes?

Comment: @devopseng You can check their source code. Just quick look now at `AWS-ASGExitStandby` document for instance shows that it does invoke some function `"FunctionName": "asg-state-change-lambda-{{automation:EXECUTION_ID}}",`. Others probably also use aws managed/created functions.